# Data is not submitted to the database and a message "ERROR" shows

Tags: php, html

There are two php files one contains the form and the other contains the code to insert the form data to the table in a database.

This is the submit form code from the first file

```
<form name="form" action="insert_dataE.php" onSubmit="return  
validation()" method="post" id="formServiceEntry">
  <fieldset id="fieldSetServiceEntry">
    <legend align="center">Please fill the form</legend>
    <p class="FieldHeading"><i>Vehicle No(*): </i></p>
    <input id="VehicleNoFieldArea" type="text" name="VehicleNoField" 
size="6" maxlength="8"/>
    <p class="FieldHeading"><i>Description(*):</i></p>
    <textarea id="descriptionFieldArea" name="descriptionField" 
rows="2" cols="20" size="15" maxlength="18"></textarea>
    <p class="FieldHeading"><i>Total(*):</i></p>
    <input id="totalFieldArea" name="totalField" type="text" 
size="4" maxlength="4"/>
    <p id="amountFieldHeading"><i>Bill(*):</i></p>
    <input id="amountFieldArea" name="amountField" type="text" 
size="3" maxlength="3" onKeyUp="balance();" />
    <br/>
    <div id="divisionRadioButton">
      <h3 id="radioButtonHeading">Service(*):</h3>
      Service &nbsp;
      <input class="textFields" type="radio" 
name="serviceSelection" value="service" checked />
      <br/>
      Wash &nbsp;
      <input class="textFields" type="radio" 
name="serviceSelection" value="wash" />
    </div>
    <p id="balanceFieldHeading"><i>Balance(*):</i></p>
    <input id="balanceFieldArea" name="balanceField" type="text" 
size="4" maxlength="4"/>
  </fieldset>
  <input class="btnsSE" type="submit" name="Button" value="Submit" />
  <input class="btnsSE" type="reset" name="Button" value="Reset Form"/>
  <input type="button"  class="btnsSE" value="Back to the staff 
interface" onClick="window.location='staffE.php';"/>
</form>
```

This is the insert data code from the second file

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database 
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "webgeek1_service", "6defyu4642070") or 
die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("webgeek1_software_order", $conn) or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application", $conn);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num_rows = $num_rows + 1;
$id= $num_rows;
$dateAndTime = date('y-m-d H:i:s',time());
$vehicleNo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['VehicleNoField']);
$description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriptionField']);
$amount=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amountField']);
$service=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['serviceSelection']);
// Build an sql statment to add the query details
$sql="INSERT INTO  `webgeek1_software_order`.`application`(`serialNo`, 
`dateAndTime` , `vehicleNo` , `description` ,`amount`,`service`) 
VALUES
('$id',      
'$dateAndTime','$vehicleNo','$description','$amount','$service')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if($result)
{
    echo "<p id='headingInsertData'>Service Station Web Application</p>";
    echo "<p id='receiptHeading'>Receipt</p>";
    echo "<div id='mainFieldsInsertData'>";
    echo  "Serial No: " . " " . $id; 
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Date and Time: " . " " . $dateAndTime;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Vehicle No: " . " " . $vehicleNo;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Description: " . " " . $description;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Amount: " . " " . $amount;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Service:" . " " . $service;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo"Thanks for using our services";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div id='footerInsertData'>";
    echo "<i>Developed by: Web Geeks - Information Technology (IT) 
    Company</i>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div align='center'>";
    echo "<input class='btns' type='button' value='Print'  
    onClick='javascript: window.print();'/>";
    echo "<input type='button'  class='btns' value='Back to the 
    Application' onClick='newDoc()'/>";
    echo "</div>";
}
else 
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Please provide full detail about your problem and error code . Also use mysqli as mysql is depreciated

Comment: I tried mysqli as well the problem persists. The problem is quite simple. My data is not submitted

Comment: Is that whole PHP code? or just a part of it?

Comment: if ($result) condition turns out to be false. It should not be false

Comment: I know it should not be false, but is this whole PHP code or not?

Comment: this is the whole php code

Comment: Ok, another thing. Can you show a screenshot how your table's **structure** looks like (`webgeek1_software_order`)?

Comment: how can i post a picture? sorry I am new to this forum

Comment: Upload in website (like http://imgur.com/). Search for guides how to upload an image.

Comment: This is the link for the image http://imgur.com/a/DR3nh

Comment: Modify line from `echo "ERROR";` to `echo "ERROR".mysql_error($conn);`, try to insert new data and write back what kind of error is this. I have a suspicion of what it could might be.

Comment: It says "ERRORDuplicate entry '51' for key 'PRIMARY' "

Comment: I must mention that my application is in two languages. Therefore, I have two copies of each file with different names definitely

Comment: I have deleted the 51 entry in the table. Now it is giving me the same error with entry 50

Comment: Yeah, I know. Hold on, I'm writing an answer to different question first, then I will in here too.

Comment: Stop using mysql_* function, use Pdo or Mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're having (`Duplicate entry '51' for key 'PRIMARY'`) seems pretty logical since you're giving your specified ID to row instead of writing automatically. Moreover, you're using ID based off of the amount of rows there currently are. This leads to MySQL error with ID duplication.

To solve this issue:

1. Modify `serialNo` column and tick a checkbox on `A_I` column (AUTO_INCREMENT). This will make sure you will always have unique `ID`.
2. Remove entirely this part in your code:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application", $conn);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 $num_rows = $num_rows + 1;
 $id= $num_rows;`

3. Modify your query:

*This is modified already*

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `webgeek1_software_order`.`application` (`dateAndTime`, `vehicleNo`, `description`,`amount`, `service`) VALUES('$dateAndTime', '$vehicleNo', '$description', '$amount', '$service')";
```

I believe database should automatically set what next ID should come after inserting new data. This will prevent your from getting such errors as ID duplication because you're no longer inserting your own number.

**A side note (but important):** you should use `mysqli` or `PDO statements` because `mysql` extension is deprecated (and is even removed in PHP 7.0.0).

Comment: Thank you very much Edvin, I was thinking that as well therefore, I implemented those things and it worked. Thank you very much again especially for the command: "mysql_error($conn)" . This command solved the issue as it gave us the idea of whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

In the structure for my table in phpmyadmin, I needed to set the column 'serialNo' to AI (Autoincrement) and in the insert data code, I needed to comment the lines:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num_rows = $num_rows + 1;
$id= $num_rows;
```

Similarly, I needed to remove the 'serialNo' from the insert query in the same file. At last I needed to comment the lines :

```
echo  "Serial No: " . " " . $id; 
echo "<br/>";
```

in the insert data code